# access scope variable from directive by name, avoiding using eval

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm new to angularJs and the [currently working example(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Gacha/UKDfu/) doesn't feel right. When you try to blur the field it should increment `event.times`, currently I doing it by `$apply` on line 10, so I'm asking is there a better way to achieve this ? Maybe something like this `var times = scope.$get(attrs.timesField);` and then `scope.$apply(function(){ times += 1; });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever a directive does not use an isolate scope and you specify a scope property using an attribute, and you want to change the value of that property, use [$parse](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24parse):

```
<input custom-field times-field="event.times" ng-model="event.title" type="text">
```

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs){
   var model = $parse(attrs.timesField);
   element.bind('blur', function(){
       model.assign(scope, model(scope) + 1);
       scope.$apply();
   });
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/mQmya/)

Answer (score 0):

You're right, that's not the correct way to do something like that.
Find out the [$watch()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch) function, especially when using it in [directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Comment: With watch I can watch variable for some changes and then do some action, but I don't want to know when the `event.times` is changed, I want to change it myself.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use eval here, you can just do this:

```
           scope.$apply(function(){
               scope.event.times++;
           });
```

However you must ensure that an event object exists on scope before using this directive and I don't think that it is good for a directive to rely on data being set elsewhere.

What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: If I do this then there is no point to pass `times-field` as attribute, I want dynamic attribute.

Comment: Yeah you are right, for some reason it didn't click that you were actually passing in the name of the field. That is absoluately the right way to do it and @marks implementation is what you want.